# Android Color - How much darker is primaryColorDark than primaryColor?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml, android-styles

I am making an application that uses a special color hex for its ***primaryColor***. Because of this, I cannot just go on Google and select a ***primaryColorDark*** to match with this color.

My question is how do you calculate the ***primaryColorDark*** based on my provided color or any ***primaryColor***?

My ***primaryColor*** that I am using is #00A478.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is plenty of color matching algorithms to calculate what you need. I have found [this site](http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=WEEL) that provides more information about the math behind them. The basic idea is to convert your color to the circle color space and find colors that are in geometric relation with your color in this space.

Also there is lot of tools on the internet that implement those algorithms and can help you finding the colors.

I have used [this tool](http://www.colorexplorer.com/colormatch.aspx) and `Single Hue` algorithm to find matching color for your **primaryColor** and found that #007052 could suit you well as **primaryColorDark**.

[image: Matching colors]

Not bad, is it? :)

Answer (score 4):

For Material Design there is a tool [MaterialPalette](http://www.materialpalette.com/). You choose your **PrimaryColor** and **AccentColor** and tool generates some well-looking colors based on your selection:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Google made a [Color tool](https://material.io/color/#!/?view.left=0&view.right=0) that allow you to pick a primary Color, and it will generate your **primaryColorDark** and your **accentColor**
It also shows you a preview of your Color choices in a few very basic layouts.